# The correct form for Baltics or Baltic

Tags: grammatical-number

I am trying to figure out the difference between Baltics and Baltic words should there be any. Imagine I was to call a company and want to use the Baltic/s word in it. Which would fit the most? Let's imagine a fictional company called CityBee. If I want to emphasize on its location in the whole Baltic states, should this be:

- CityBee Baltics
- CityBee Baltic

Comment: this question seems purely opinion-based so cannot really be answered well on this site. In my mind "Baltics" would refer specifically to the Baltic states (i.e. Estonia, Latvia, & Lithuania, although note that whilst the latter two do speak Baltic languages, Estonian is a Finnic language, and non-Indo-European), but "Baltic" would refer to the entire region surrounding the sea and so might also include any of Northern Poland, Northern Germany, Denmark, Sweden, Finland, and Northwestern Russia

Answer (score 2):

*Baltics* is not a common expression. The GloWbE corpus has 145 instances,
against 3151 of *Baltic*. Of course you can call your company whatever you want.